# Documentation of Sonatype emma-maven-plugin and emma4it-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, code-coverage, emma

Did anybody know where one can find the documentation for the both sonartype plugins emma-maven-plugin and emma4it-maven-plugin?

```
<groupId>org.sonatype.maven.plugin</groupId>
<artifactId>emma-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>

<groupId>org.sonatype.maven.plugin</groupId>
<artifactId>emma4it-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.3</version>
```

I only know this blog:  [Integration Tests with Maven (Part 2): Test Coverage Reports](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/06/integration-tests-with-maven-part-2-test-coverage-reports/) that makes my try to use the pluins, but this blog that is far away form an documentation.

Comment: @who downvoted the question: Is it really a so stupid question? So stupid that you can not answer it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site for the plugins doesn't seemed to be published. However you can read the APT (almost plain text) pages documentation.

https://github.com/sonatype/emma-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/site/apt/howto.apt
  https://github.com/sonatype/emma-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/site/apt/introduction.apt

It looks like it has similar src to http://mojo.codehaus.org/emma-maven-plugin, so you may want to try one of the other emma maven plugins.